# How to get all use statements declared in PHP class file

Tags: php, namespaces

Lets say I have a following class:

```
<?php
namespace ImTheVendor\Project5;

use ImTheVendor\Project1\SomeClass,
    ImTheVendor\Project2\SomeOtherClass;
use ImTheVendor\Project5\SomeClass;

class Something
{

}
```

How can I get all namespaces declared with use statement? Do I have to regexp the file itself or is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: You should use a *parser*, e.g.: https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser

Comment: BTW, you don't use leading ``\`` in `namespace` or `use` statements. It's just `namespace ImTheVendor\..` and `use ImTheVendor\..`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the TokenFinderTool::getUseDependencies method.

```
$f = $modulesDir . "/Bat/FileSystemTool.php";
$tokens = token_get_all(file_get_contents($f));
$dependencies = TokenFinderTool::getUseDependencies($tokens);
```

Also, it has a method that find all "use statements" inside a given directory:

```
$dir = $modulesDir . "/Bat";
$deps = TokenFinderTool::getUseDependenciesByFolder($dir);
```

A working example can be found here: https://github.com/lingtalfi/TokenFun#tokenfindertool

Also, there is another solution described in this post: 
[Easiest way to detect/remove unused `use` statements from PHP codebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895502/easiest-way-to-detect-remove-unused-use-statements-from-php-codebase)

Comment: How can you install `TokenFinderTool`, the Github's README.md does not explain it. There's something written about `planet`, but I do not know how to use it