# Getting multiple subpatterns with the same name

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

Regarding my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28204942/how-to-get-all-use-statements-declared-in-php-class-file?noredirect=1#comment44776367_28204942) I'm trying to match with regular expressions all use statements in a class file.

```
<?php
use Vendor\ProjectArticle\Model\Peer,
    Vendor\Library\Template;
use Vendor\Blablabla;

$file = file_get_contents($class_path);
$a = preg_match_all('#use (?:(?<ns>[^,;]+),?)+;#mi', $file, $use);
var_dump(array('$a' => $a, '$use' => $use));
```

Unfortunately I'm not blessed with all namespaces used in case of multiple class names in one use statement. Only last one matched is being stored.

```
Array
(
    [$a] => 2
    [$use] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => use Vendor\ProjectArticle\Model\Peer,
    Vendor\Library\Template;
                    [1] => use Vendor\Blablabla;
                )

            [ns] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
    Vendor\Library\Template
                    [1] => Vendor\Blablabla
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
    Vendor\Library\Template
                    [1] => Vendor\Blablabla
                )
        )
)
```

Can this be accomplished with some pattern modifier or something?

~Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to use the `\G` anchor for this.

```
 # '~(?:(?!\A)\G|^Use\s+),?\s*(?<ns>[^,;]+)(?=(?:,|[^,;]*)*;)~mi'

 (?xmi-)                       # Inline modifier = expanded, multiline, case insensitive
 (?:
      (?! \A )                      # Not beginning of string
      \G                            # If matched before, start at end of last match
   |                              # or,
      ^ Use \s+                     # Beginning of line then 'Use' + whitespace 
 )

 ,? \s*                        # Whitespace trim
 (?<ns> [^,;]+ )               # (1), A namespace value

 (?=                           # Lookahead, each match validates a final ';'
      (?: , | [^,;]* )*
      ;
 )
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 36 ) 
use Vendor\ProjectArticle\Model\Peer
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 4 , len 32 ) 
Vendor\ProjectArticle\Model\Peer

---------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 36 , len 30 ) 
,
    Vendor\Library\Template
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 43 , len 23 ) 
Vendor\Library\Template

---------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 69 , len 20 ) 
use Vendor\Blablabla
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 73 , len 16 ) 
Vendor\Blablabla
```

Comment: You have just blown me away with this reply. Wow really... (?!\A) means NOT the begining of a string within a scope of a single line, right?

Comment: @starach - Yeah, `\G` is the try to match after previous match construct. When applied on a new string, `\G` is in the _TRUE_ state by default, ie. when it first tries to match. This position is where `\A` is. To flip `\G` to _FALSE_ at this time and position, a `(?!\A)` is necessary.after which the `(?!\A)` assertion will never be false, so it procedes to check for the truism of `\G`. Remember that `\G` maintains an internal flag true/false.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but could you send me or repost that response you made on my [second problem link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28270832/capturing-all-method-arguments-default-values). I think it pretty much solved my problem but had to go afk and when I came back they blocked my topic and now even though it has been unlocked your reply is missing.

Comment: @starach - Ok, its undeleted. I deleted it because it looked like you were trying to do other things besides parsing quoted strings, which to me looked untenable.